# Getting error when try to parsing JSON Response with quotation marks

Tags: json, swift, codable

I have JSON Respose from API like this:

```
[{
  "id":"6",
  "name":"Лилия",
  "description":"Сауна "Лилия" ждёт всех тех, кто хочет отдохнуть от суеты в специально созданной для этого атмосфере тепла и уюта. В Вашем распоряжении 3 жаркие сауны, комнаты отдыха, 3 бассейна (один длиной 14 м), в котором Вы можете прекрасно поплавать. Для Вашего удобства всегда в продаже берёзовые и дубовые веники. При желании можно заказать блюда европейской кухни и напитки прямо в сауну. Рады видеть Вас в нашей сауне круглосуточно! Стоимость саун от 350 руб./час - более подробную информацию уточняйте у администратора"
}]
```

Trying to decode it to my Model
But getting error:

> dataCorrupted(Swift.DecodingError.Context(codingPath: [], debugDescription: "The given data was not valid JSON.", underlyingError: Optional(Error Domain=NSCocoaErrorDomain Code=3840 "Badly formed object around character 58." UserInfo={NSDebugDescription=Badly formed object around character 58.})))

My code:

```swift
class NetworkService {
    var companies = [Company]()
    let session = URLSession(configuration: .default)

    func getCompanies(stringUrl: String) {

        guard let url = URL(string: stringUrl) else { return }

        let task = session.dataTask(with: url) { (data, response, error) in
            guard let dataResponse = data, error == nil else {
                    print(error?.localizedDescription ?? "Response Error")
                    return
            }

            do {
                self.companies = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Company>.self, from: dataResponse)
            } catch let parsingError {
                print("error", parsingError)
            }
        }

        task.resume()
    }
}
```

Model:

```swift
struct Company: Codable {
    let name: String
    let description: String?
}
```

Comment: Is is a coincidence that the word in quotes in `description` is the same as the one in `name` or is that a pattern?

Comment: it's a coincidence. translate is something like this: { "name": "Lilia", "descripition": "Sauna "Lilia" is waiting for all of you who wanted to has a rest ...." }

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Correct json ( you need to add escaping `\` before any `"` inside `description` 's key value)

```
[{
    "id": "6",
    "name": "Лилия",
    "description": "Сауна \" Лилия \" ждёт всех тех, кто хочет отдохнуть от суеты в специально созданной для этого атмосфере тепла и уюта. В Вашем распоряжении 3 жаркие сауны, комнаты отдыха, 3 бассейна (один длиной 14 м), в котором Вы можете прекрасно поплавать. Для Вашего удобства всегда в продаже берёзовые и дубовые веники. При желании можно заказать блюда европейской кухни и напитки прямо в сауну. Рады видеть Вас в нашей сауне круглосуточно! Стоимость саун от 350 руб./час - более подробную информацию уточняйте у администратора"
}]
```

---

Try

```
let str = String(data:data, encoding: .utf8)
let actual = str.replacingOccurrences(of: "Сауна \" Лилия \"", with: "Сауна \\" Лилия \\"")
```

Then change this

```
 self.companies = try JSONDecoder().decode(Array<Company>.self, from: Data(actual.utf8))
```

Comment: Thanks, but I don't have access to API

Comment: any workaround will work for this specific response try to contact the web developer to change that response

Answer (score 0):

Попытаюсь я:

```
import Foundation

let badJsonString = "{\"id\":\"2\",\"description\":\"any \"bad\" description\"}"
let okJsonString  = badJsonString.replacingOccurrences(of: #"(?<= )\"|\"(?= )"#, with: "'", options: .regularExpression)
let jsonData = try JSONSerialization.jsonObject(with: Data(okJsonString.utf8))
print(jsonData)
```

Comment: This is just code without any description, please explain how this solves the problem